# Assiging model record to more than one user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a rails app and one of the features lets you give virtual gifts to other users.

One user gives a gift(through a Gift model) to another user. One user is the giver(Gift.giver) The other user is the receiver (Gift.receiver)

**My question is how do I assign each gift to two users, the giver and the receiver, so that I can later call User.gifts_received to get the list of gifts the user received and User.gifts_given to get the list of gifts the user gave?**

Is it better to just have User.gifts instead of User.gifts_received and User.gifts_given? I plan on using the acts_as_follower gem to let users see all gifts given and received by users they follow.

In past apps, when a user created a post, the post belonged to that one user, which I assigned with:

```
@post.user = current_user
```

And how could I use the [acts_as_follower gem](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower) to get all the gifts that one user that another user follows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing your gift model looks something like this:

**gift.rb**

```
class Gift < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :giver, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :receiver, class_name: 'User'

  ...
end
```

So to do this, you will need to make your user model look something like this, with acts_as_follower stuff added:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :given_gifts, class_name: 'Gift', foreign_key: 'giver_id'
  has_many :received_gifts, class_name: 'Gift', foreign_key: 'receiver_id'

  acts_as_followable
  acts_as_follower

  ...
end
```

You will need these to be part of your gift migration:

```
f.integer :receiver_id
f.integer :giver_id
```

Which gives you access to these methods when assigned:

```
giver = User.first
receiver = User.last
gift = Gift.create(giver: giver, receiver: receiver)
gift.giver => giver
gift.receiver => receiver
giver.given_gifts => [gift]
receiver.received_gifts => [gift]
```

And acts_as_follower methods (using variables above):

```
giver.follow(receiver)
Gift.where(receiver_id: giver.all_following.pluck(:id)) => [gift]
```

`where` allows you to pass in an array of values to be queried against in the DB (which `all_following` returns).

[Acts as follower gem](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower).

[Check this out](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins) for more information.

Comment: Thank you soooooooooooooooooo much!! :))) How would I use the acts_as_follower gem to show the gifts given and received by all the users you follow? https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower

Comment: Does one user follow another user? Or is there a separate class following users?

Comment: One user follows another user. Each user is following a bunch of other users like on Twitter.

Comment: Yup, it's simply the User class involved in all the following behaviors!

Comment: Hey Ken!! Can you take a look at this question. I really appreciate your help with setting up the model. Now i'm trying to grab gifts to fill in activity feeds. For any given user, in their feed, i'd like to show all the gifts given by and received by the users that user follows, without showing duplicates, being able to order them by the creation time, and being able to paginate them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27586680/retreiving-posts-of-all-users-that-a-user-follows-rails-activerecord/27586979

Answer (score 0):

If I was you, I would consider using the acts as tenant gem:

[Acts as Tenant Gem](https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant)

This gem allows you to scope and set tenacity so depending on what the account is, you can find all gifts associated with a given user.