# Retrieving posts of all users that a user follows - rails - ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a simple rails app where users can give virtual gifts to each other. Each gift belongs to two users, the giver and the receiver.

In my **User.rb**

```
has_many :given_gifts, class_name: 'Gift', foreign_key: 'giver_id'
  has_many :received_gifts, class_name: 'Gift', foreign_key: 'receiver_id'

  acts_as_followable
  acts_as_follower
```

In my **Gift.rb**

```
belongs_to :giver, class_name: 'User'
belongs_to :receiver, class_name: 'User'
```

I'm using the [acts_as_follower gem](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower) to allow users to follow other users and see the list of gifts that the users they follow gave and received.

In my controller:

```
id = current_user.id
@given_gifts = User.find(id).following_users.includes(:given_gifts).collect{|u| u.given_gifts}.flatten

@received_gifts = User.find(id).following_users.includes(:received_gifts).collect{|u| u.received_gifts}.flatten

@gifts = @given_gifts.zip(@received_gifts).flatten.compact
```

I'm sure I'm doing this really wrong. This gives me a list of gifts, with some duplicates, and they are all out of order. **How can I efficiently grab the list of all gifts given and received by the users that any given user follows, so they there are no duplicates, they are all in order, and so that i can paginate the results?**

If as a user, I am following user X and user Y, and user X gave user Y a gift, in my feed I only want to see one mention of this instead of two mentions of this same gift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a custom method in my Gift model, try this:

**gift.rb**

```
class Gift < ActiveResource::Base

...

def self.all_gifts(user_id)
  follower_ids = User.find(user_id).following_users.pluck(:id)
  Gift.where('giver_id in (?) OR receiver_id in (?)', follower_ids, follower_ids).uniq
end

...
```

This will end up generating and running a SQL call that looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "gifts".* FROM "gifts" WHERE (giver_id in (1,2,3) OR receiver_id in (1,2,3))
```

Given that users with IDs 1, 2, and 3 follow the user. You should be able to paginate these results like this in your controller:

```
id = current_user.id
Gift.all_gifts(id).paginate # any paginate attributes
```

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much!! Now I'm getting the error message: undefined local variable or method `id' for #<Class:0x007fd1136aac48>  the highlighted line is:  follower_ids = User.find(id).following_users.pluck(:id)

Comment: I just changed the parameter in the method from user_id to id, and it works now! You are amaaaaaazing!!!! Is there any way I can give you more points!!?!? :))))

Answer (score 0):

Tested this on Rails 4 and **associations**(not the gem). This will give distinct gift records ordered by created_at :-

@gifts = User.find(id).following_users.joins(:received_gifts, :given_gifts).select('DISTINCT gifts. *')

Also as per the [documentation](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower), I think you should use **followers_scoped** instead of **followers** inorder to get an Arel scope instead of an array of elements

Comment: How do I retrieve the received gifts and the given gifts?

Comment: @received_gifts = User.find(id).following_users.joins(:received_gifts).select('gifts. *')

Comment: Thanks again, but I think you may be misunderstanding my question. Your answers shows how I can retrieve the :received_gifts, but I am trying to retrieve both the :received_gifts and the :given_gifts.

Comment: what about this, @gifts = User.find(id).following_users.joins(:received_gifts, :given_gifts).select('DISTINCT gifts. *')

Comment: Thanks again, but this gives me a list of users instead of gifts :(

Comment: Can you provide me the output that you are getting as we are selecting only the attributes of gifts here and thus even if it looks like its a user record, it actually only contains gift record, your output will help me debug it faster :)